# QOQ growth Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**i have query**

```sql
select a.`2021`,
       b.`2022`,
       a.product, 
       concat(ceil((b.`2022`-a.`2021`)/ a.`2021` * 100), '%')  as growth 
from ( SELECT SUM(total) as `2021`,
              product,
              sum
       FROM table
       WHERE YEAR(month) = 2021
         AND case when day(CURRENT_DATE()) > 10 
             then  QUARTER(month) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
             else  QUARTER(month) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
             end 
       GROUP BY Product , 
             YEAR(month) )a
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(total) as `2022`,
              Product
       FROM table
       WHERE YEAR(month) = 2022
         AND case when day(CURRENT_DATE()) > 10 
             then  QUARTER(month) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
             else  QUARTER(month) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
             end 
       GROUP BY Product , 
             YEAR(month) ) b on a.Product=b.Product;
```

**if the current date is not the end of the quarter then the data that appears is the data in the previous quarter period**

Comment: What is `sum` in the output list of `a` subquery? misprint?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: example today date 09-06-22 display output just before quarter now

Comment: if the current date is not the end of the quarter then the data that appears is the data in the previous quarter period  @Akina